# Exist a solution to group on-demand with jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grouping, ondemand

I'm want to create a jqGrid with grouping:true, but only first group expanded and another groups stay collapsed when expand this group, was been collapsed, I need to load the data from the server.

Someone has a solution for that?

PS: I need use grouping, why the user can be select another columns to group on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement your requirements you should use `groupCollapse: true` to have all groups displayed in collapsed form. For example like

```
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ['invdate'],
    groupCollapse: true,
    groupDataSorted: true
}
```

and then expand the first group with respect of [groupingToggle](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping#methods) after the grid are filled. For example you can use the following code inside of `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this), firstGroup = $this.find('tr.jqgroup:first');
    if (firstGroup.length > 0) {
        $this.jqGrid('groupingToggle', firstGroup[0].id);
    }
}
```

If you remind the fact how the ids of the grouping rows of the grid will be constructed you can reduce the code to the following

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid('groupingToggle', this.id + 'ghead_0');
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandFirstGrouping.htm).

To change on the fly the column used for grouping you can use `groupingGroupBy` method:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', columnName);
```

For example `$("#list").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', 'ship_via');`. You should understand that the new `groupField` will be used only after the next filling of the grid body. So if you want to define on the server the grouping order and include it in the server response you should call `groupingGroupBy` method inside of `beforeProcessing` and not inside of `loadComplete`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll try and reply for some problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

set your datatype:'local'

then

$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);